# During boot process message "failed command READ FPDMA QUEUED"

Tags: boot, fsck

My computer booted to a black screen with this error message.

Welcome to emergency mode! After logging in,type "journalctl -xb" to view
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or ^D to
try again to boot into default mode.

journalctl -xb snippet (what I think is wrong):

```
ápr 19 19:25:17 agylaptop kernel: ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1c0800 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
ápr 19 19:25:17 agylaptop kernel: ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ápr 19 19:25:17 agylaptop kernel: ata1.00: cmd 60/08:58:80:a8:29/00:00:05:00:00/40 tag 11 ncq dma 4096 in
```

lines 1197-1219

```
ápr 19 19:25:17 agylaptop kernel: ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ápr 19 19:25:17 agylaptop kernel: ata1.00: cmd 60/00:90:80:6c:93/01:00:09:00:00/40 tag 18 ncq dma 131072 in
                                            res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
ápr 19 19:25:17 agylaptop kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
```

Following that the next boot is slow but successful. However, the WiFi is not able to connect to the router.
In this situation I can make some improvement by using a UBUNTU Live from a USB store. I run:

```
$ sudo -i
$ fsck  -Cccfv /dev/sda8  

         sda8  is the home partition on my  disk.
```

The same error occurs after a 3 - 4 days long period.
What should I do?

Comment: Please start a separate new question for the wifi problem.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**NCQ errors**

Your disk subsystem is getting ncq errors...

```
ápr 19 19:25:17 agylaptop kernel: ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ápr 19 19:25:17 agylaptop kernel: ata1.00: cmd 60/00:90:80:6c:93/01:00:09:00:00/40 tag 18 ncq dma 131072 in
                                            res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
ápr 19 19:25:17 agylaptop kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
```

Native Command Queuing (NCQ) is an extension of the Serial ATA protocol allowing hard disk drives to internally optimize the order in which received read and write commands are executed.

Edit `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` and change the following line to include this extra parameter. Then do `sudo update-grub` to write the changes to disk. Reboot. Monitor hangs, and watch `/var/log/syslog` or `dmesg` for continued error messages.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash libata.force=noncq"
```

Comment: I edited sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub and changed the line witch defines the value of GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT. Then I did  sudo update-grub to write the changes to disk. I rebooted 4 times. I work on the system and monitor hangs however, no hang occured.  Thank you for the solution.

Comment: @GyorgyAntos You're very welcome!