# failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED. Should I replace HDD?

Tags: boot, hard-drive

Unfortunately after a blackout my small home media server went down. Now when I try to start it up again I get various errors, among which I often get `ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED`. The system then get's stuck and I don't even get a prompt.

Now, from what I understand from other AskUbuntu questions this is due to my HDD failing. The problem is that what's failing is the main HDD, so is there anything I can do? I didn't have any important information there, just a fresh install of the OS with some configs.

Is there any way to restore the system, or should I format and fresh install? Is the HDD damaged forever, and should I replace the disk?

Comment: You've provided few specifics.. firstly I'd explore what you were running, and if it's a Ubuntu LTS release which kernel stack you opted to use (*default set by installation media you opted to use*).  In interpreting kernel messages I'll suggest you work out the OS/release & kernel stack details so as to interpret correctly.  Do you exploration from a *live* system and **not** your installed system, and I'd rely on SMART as to drive health (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools) more than  a kernel boot message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [During boot process message "failed command READ FPDMA QUEUED"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232188/during-boot-process-message-failed-command-read-fpdma-queued)